# go application debugging using dlv exe .looking for commands to run in headless mode

Tags: go, debugging, delve

Starting debugging using `dlv exec --headless` package.

It shows:

```
API server listening at: 127.0.0.1:54207
debugserver-@(#)PROGRAM:LLDB  PROJECT:lldb-1316.0.9.41
for arm64.
Got a connection, launched process
```

After that it shows nothing.

Checking what kind of commands should be tried after that to setup breakpoints.

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of Go are you using?

Comment: go: stable 1.18.1 on m1 macbook

Comment: Ok, that's fine. This may help: https://golang.cafe/blog/golang-debugging-with-delve.html

Comment: thanks. this does not help. adding snapshot where it comes and looking for what commands can be used once reaching there.

Comment: bazel run --compilation_mode=dbg --run_under='dlv exec --headless  'package'
application needs to run with bazel.

Comment: This is resolved. in one terminal run dlv exec --headless and another terminal run dlv connect.